# Catalyst 3560G SPAN session not mirroring IGMP packets

Tags: wireshark, multicast, cisco-catalyst, igmp

I am developing a device which acts as a multicast host, and want to observe it as it responds to IGMP Queries.

My Catalyst 3560G is set up as follows (full config below):  Port 0/1 is a TFTP server allowing the device under test to boot.  Port 0/3 is the device under test.  Port 0/14 is my PC running wireshark, and ostinato for sending the IGMP query.  Ports 0/1 and 0/3 are on a VLAN together, and port 0/14 is monitoring port 0/3, with ingress sent to that same VLAN.  Those are the only three ports on the switch connected to anything.

When I send the query, Wireshark captures the outgoing frame, and nothing else.  My device under test receives the frame (I get debug output).

I would expect that the SPAN session would send me a copy of the IGMP query as it egresses on port 0/3, and a copy of the corresponding report when it ingresses port 0/3, but I see neither of these.  The only indication I have that the device under test responds at all is the multicast received counter on Port 0/3, which increments at the right time (0-10 seconds after the query was sent).

What am I doing wrong?

```
Current configuration : 2490 bytes
!
version 12.2
no service pad
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname cs3560
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
enable secret 5 $1$WKu9$g6YTo5sW/vvVmpbVmgTye0
!
no aaa new-model
system mtu routing 1500
ip subnet-zero
no ip dhcp use vrf connected
!
no ip igmp snooping
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
vlan internal allocation policy ascending
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
switchport access vlan 161
switchport mode access
!
! <snip>  uninvolved ports removed
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
switchport access vlan 161
switchport mode access
spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/14
!
no cdp run
!
control-plane
!
line con 0
line vty 0 4
password 123
login
line vty 5 15
password 123
login
!
monitor session 1 source interface Gi0/3
monitor session 1 destination interface Gi0/14 ingress untagged vlan 161
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using these commands:

```
monitor session 1 source interface Gi0/3 /both/

monitor session 1 destination interface Gi0/14 ingress untagged vlan 161
end
```